# why isn't saga function accepting a request for the 2nd time around?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, redux, redux-saga

so I am guessing I am doing something fundamentally wrong. When I upload an image from the browser the first time, the below function triggers but it only happens once. so next time I upload an image, I don't see watchFileReader function running again.. so strange that it is happening..because I am getting other saga function to behave as expected! 
Could someone tell me what I may be doing wrong?

```
export function* watchFileReader() {
  const action = yield take("DROP_FILE")
  console.log('action', action)
  let file = action.file[0];
  readFile(file, function(e) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('img')
    console.log('alskdjfalsdjkf', e.target.result)
    sessionStorage.setItem('img', e.target.result)
  })
}

export const readFile = (file, callback) => {
  let reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onloadend = callback;
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
}

export function* rootSaga() {
  yield [
    watchFileReader()
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [take](https://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/api/index.html#takepattern) effect only gets yielded once. You can either stick the watcher code inside a while loop, or use the [takeEvery](https://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/api/index.html#takeeverypattern-saga-args) helper from redux-saga.

Because its a generator function, the saga is suspended until the action is caught by the middleware and yielded again, so its not like you'll have a bunch of infinite loops whirring around in the background hogging cpu.

I use the same design patterns as a lot of the docs, which is to have a 'watcher' saga / process that runs on a loop to take every action dispatched, and fires of a worker saga or process that does the real heavy lifting.

TakeEvery (or takeLatest if you only want the latest one fetched) acts like a forever-running while loop, and each time it gets the action its looking for, forks a new worker, which makes it a non-blocking operation.

```
export function* fileReaderWorker(action) {
  console.log('action', action)
  let file = action.file[0];
  readFile(file, function(e) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('img')
    console.log('alskdjfalsdjkf', e.target.result)
    sessionStorage.setItem('img', e.target.result)
  })
}

export function* watchFileReader() {
  yield takeEvery("DROP_FILE", fileReaderWorker)
}
// or the loop version
// while (true) {
//  const action = yield take("DROP_FILE")
//  yield fork(fileReaderWorker, ...args.concat(action))
//}

export const readFile = (file, callback) => {
  let reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onloadend = callback;
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
}

export function* rootSaga() {
  yield [
    watchFileReader()
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick help on this..also do you know how I would pass e.target.result to the state reducer. seems like if i do yield put({type: "ENCODE", {img: e.target.result}}) in replacing sessionStorage.setItem('img', e.target.result)  I get an exception.

Comment: what's the exception you're getting?

Comment: it says unexpected token.                                                                     Module build failed:                                                                          SyntaxError: /home/console_2/static/app/sagas.js: Unexpected token (153:6)
  151 |       sessionStorage.removeItem('img')
  152 |       sessionStorage.setItem('img', e.target.result)
> 153 |       yield put({type: "ENCODE"})
      |       ^
  154 |     })
  155 | }

Answer (score 0):

After the first file is dropped, the status of saga generator `function` would be suspended i.e `{done: false}`. To keep the status as active you can either wrap your yield `function` in an `infinite while loop`:

```
export function* watchFileReader() {
  while(true) {
   const action = yield take("DROP_FILE")
   console.log('action', action)
   let file = action.file[0];
   readFile(file, function(e) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('img')
    console.log('alskdjfalsdjkf', e.target.result)
    sessionStorage.setItem('img', e.target.result)
  })
 }
}
```

or make use of the takeEvery or [takeLatest](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/UsingSagaHelpers.html) side-effect provided by redux-saga.